# Select all rows having duplicate phone numbers with different zone codes?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table called `contacts` with following fields:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | phone_no     |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Suppose, I have have following values in this table :

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | phone_no     |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | Alex  | 9907661234   |--1, 2 are 
| 2  | Alex  | 09907661234  |--Same contacts but preceding with '0'
| 3  | John  | 9879612363   |--Same contacts but preceding with '91'
| 4  | John  | 919879612363 |-- 91 is (country code)
| 5  | Shawn | 9979867123   |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

I want to find number of duplicate contacts with duplicate numbers (here numbers preceded) with `0` and `91` are duplicates.

I want following output :

```
+------------+-------------+
| phone_no   |     cn      |
+------------+-------------+
| 9879612363 |           2 |
| 9907661234 |           2 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Note in MySQL comment starts with `--` but not `//`, So SO CSS enable comment class when you uses `--` with MySQL tag. Any ways very intresting question.

Comment: How many codes you uses only `91`  and `0`?

Comment: Possible prefixes are 1. `0` from within `India` and 2. `+91` from within and outside of `India`. Prefix is *optional* when *within* `India`.

Comment: why you insert them like that ? why dont you control them by javascript or php before you insert them and it will be sure that they enter just single number phone.

Comment: Using `+` *with country code* is a must and `0` a *must* within country and outside of a state.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes any country code can be used.I guess taking last 10 digits can work fine.Please Suggest.

Comment: Then change part of the db design. Separate country code to a different field or table. And decide whether to prefix with country code to send SMS or a call request.

Comment: @echo_Me : Thanks for suggesting.However its an opensource SugarCRM that allows to enter in any format.

Comment: @user3286692 If any code can be allowed then ph. can be only 10 digits?

Comment: @Ravinder : You are right but I cant change the structure.Its an already built SugarCRM system.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have phone numbers are 10  chars (as you shown in your question) and optionally prefixed by some codes. Then you can use [`RIGHT(str,len)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function in MySQL that return the specified rightmost number of characters.

The query will be as follows(read comments):

```
SELECT  RIGHT(`phone_no`, 10) as `mobile`,  -- selecting last 10 digits
        count(*) as `tatal_count`
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY `mobile`  -- group by last ten digits
HAVING count(`mobile`) > 1;  -- if you want to select on duplicates
```

Working example:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
  `id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**Insert Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `details` VALUES 
("1", "Alex", "9907661234"),
("2", "Alex", "09907661234"),
("3", "John", "9879612363"),
("4", "John", "919879612363"),
("5", "Shawn", "9979867123");
```

**[ANSWER]**

```
mysql> SELECT  RIGHT(`phone`, 10) as `mobile`, 
    ->         count(*) as `tatal_count`
    -> FROM `details`
    -> GROUP BY `mobile`
    -> ;
+------------+-------------+
| mobile     | tatal_count |
+------------+-------------+
| 9879612363 |           2 |
| 9907661234 |           2 |
| 9979867123 |           1 |
+------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Suppose if you wants only  numbers those duplicates (more than one) then youcan use HAVING clause in MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT  RIGHT(`phone`, 10) as `mobile`, 
    ->         count(*) as `tatal_count`
    -> FROM `details`
    -> GROUP BY `mobile`
    -> HAVING count(`mobile`) > 1;
+------------+-------------+
| mobile     | tatal_count |
+------------+-------------+
| 9879612363 |           2 |
| 9907661234 |           2 |
+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

<sup>I am not check that codes are, and assuming you have valid mobile numbers in DB</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't test it because I don't have an MySQL server here. But maybe you can use the following:

```
SELECT
    IF (
        phone_no REGEXP '^91' AND LENGTH(phone_no) = 12,
            SUBSTRING(phone_no, 3),
            IF (
                phone_no REGEXP '^0'  AND LENGTH(phone_no) = 11,
                    SUBSTRING(phone_no, 2),
                    phone_no
            )
    ) AS phoneNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    `table` 
GROUP BY 
    phoneNumber
```

Replace the 'table' by your own table name.

What this query does, if checking if the phone number begins with 91 or 0. If so, it strips of the first 2 or 1 characters. After getting the correct number, we can use the 'phoneNumber' column for grouping.

EDIT: Also added 'LENGTH' in the query, just to be sure normal numbers are not being stripped.

Comment: Lolz.. I wrote SQL instead of MySQL, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Select the numbers in to a temporary table, stripping leading zeros, or where the number is over a specified length and the leading digits match a country code, cut them off.

You can then do a search on your temporary table for duplicates.

Comment: Can you please suggest the query for same.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
 $phone_number as phone_number, count(phone_number) as cnt 
from my_table 
where phone_number like concat( '%', $phone_number )
group by concat( '%', $phone_number )
```

Comment: '$phone_number' in MySQL?

Comment: @Benz: Cool. It is just a suggestion. I think OP seems have idea understanding it. And for others: Use your scripting language to replace `$phone_number` either with a place holder ( for prepared statements ) or a valid value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN phone_no LIKE '0%' THEN SUBSTR(phone_no FROM 2)
    WHEN phone_no LIKE '91%' THEN SUBSTR(phone_no FROM 3)
    ELSE phone_no
  END phone_no,
  COUNT(*) duplicates
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN phone_no LIKE '0%' THEN SUBSTR(phone_no FROM 2)
    WHEN phone_no LIKE '91%' THEN SUBSTR(phone_no FROM 3)
    ELSE phone_no
  END
HAVING
  COUNT(*)>1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af8a0f/1).

Answer (score 2):

i think you looking for this

```
select if(left(phone_no ,3) = 091 , substring( phone_no,4) ,
       if(left(phone_no ,1)= 0, substring( phone_no,2),
       if(left(phone_no ,2) = 91 , substring( phone_no,3), phone_no))) as phones, count(*) counts

from contacts
group by phones
having count(*)>1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8302f/19)

Or esayily to select  last 10 digits of your number phones

```
   select RIGHT(`phone_no`, 10) as phones , count(*) counts
   from contacts
   group by phones
   having count(*)>1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8302f/20)

OUTPUT:

```
PHONES      COUNTS
9879612363  2
9907661234  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this answer. May be it will work.

```
select phone_no, count(*)
  from table_name
  group by phone_no
  having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: No it doesn't helps out desired result